# Getting a route from MethodInfo in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, mvc, asp.net-core

Is it possible that given a `MethodInfo` object, i can somehow figure out what the MVC registered route would be for that method?

I've tried something along the lines of checking if the `MethodInfo` has a `Route` attribute, and checking if the class also has a `Route` attribute, and if they don't have one then just generating a string like `$"/{classNameWithoutController}/{methodName}"`

Is there a better way? Is it even feasible?

Comment: Doesn't sound easy.  Not sure it is possible.  Maybe take a look at [this Visual Studio add-in](http://mvcroutevisualizer.codeplex.com/) and reverse engineer it.